# Product of random numbers.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, random

Find the constant $p$ such that the product of any (positive) number $N_0$ multiplied by successive random numbers between $0$ and $p$ will, on average, neither diverge to infinity nor converge to zero.

(This is not for homework or anything. This is a problem I "invented" and solved, and now want to see how real mathematicians would think about this. Take your time.)

(Thanks md2perpe for fixing up my tag.)

(Thanks Forester for making the variables render nicely.)

Comment: Did you want to create your own tag containing 'random'?

Comment: This is a dupe, but I can't find the target. But, the answer is $p=e$.

Comment: The answer might depend on how the random numbers are distributed between $0$ and $p$.

Comment: @fleablood It doesn't matter whether it includes $0$, since $\{0\}$ is a measure $0$ set. And no, the answer is $p=e$. Can't seem to find the duplicate, though, and I am too lazy to explain why.

Comment: @md2perpe The reasonable assumption is the uniform distribution, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. I leave you to fill missing details.

Call $X_n$ the random variable which is uniformly distributed in the interval $(0,p)$.
Then
$$\prod_{n=1}^N X_n \mbox{ is bounded and stays away from zero} \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^N \log X_n \mbox{ is bounded }$$
The random variables $\log X_n$ has values in the interval $(- \infty , \log p)$, and it is not uniformly distributed.
Clearly, a necessary condition of $$\sum_{n=1}^N \log X_n \mbox{ is bounded }$$
is that the mean of $\log X_n$ is zero.

Hence we need
$$\int_{0}^{ p} \log t \  \mathrm d t =0 $$
this condition is equivalent to
$$p \log p -p =0$$

This equation in the variable $p >0$ is easily solved and the only positive solution is $p=e$.

Answer (score 0):

On reflection, I'm not sure the question is correct as stated.

If one takes the arithmetic average of the answer, even with p=e, this will tend to become very large - because you will get the odd case where you are multiplying by numbers bigger than 1 consistently.  You only need a few such numbers for the arithmetic average to blow up.

Perhaps as you multiply by more and more such numbers, the average will come down(?) but I’m not sure.

Alternatively, the question could be reformulated to be about some kind of geometric average?

Comment: Thanks for your comments William G. I am completely open to suggestions on how to restate the problem, especially because I know I'm hinging a lot on the phrase "on average"... However this problem does capture a "real" phenomenon in the sense that if one writes some code to explore the question, you will notice that p=e will surely drag the overall product all over the number line, but it does not take off to infinity nor settle to zero. I would have to study more to make the following comment in confidence, but the log of the result seems to take a random walk up and down the reals.

Comment: I think what you’re proving is that the answer is N_0*F, where log(F) has an expectation of zero.  But this doesn’t mean that F has an expectation of 1, because F is a random variable.  In fact, Log(F) will get more and more volatile as you multiply by more and more random numbers, and that volatility means the expectation of F keeps growing.  The arithmetic average of your simulation will (I think) tend to infinity.  The answer is probably to look at higher order moments of the distribution and allow for them (biased estimators etc).

Comment: I think the answer to the original question is actually 2.  It’s N_0*E(X_1*...*X_n) where E denotes expectation, and the X_i are independent random variables uniformly distributed between 0 and p.  This equals N_0*E(X_1)*...*E(X_n), and the expectation of each X_i will be 1 if p=2.

Comment: Hello again William G. Funny enough, I had also wondered if p=2 was the answer right at first, so I set up a little code to check this... and p=2 failed miserably (every test went to zero quickly). To find the number that *did* do what I was wanting, it was a matter of fine-tuning until p=e was surely it. (I think the arguments we tossed around on this page are pretty solid.)

Comment: If you run the simulation enough times with p=e, you’ll see stray cases where the product tends to a very large number, blowing up the arithmetic average, whereas your approach will stabilise the geometric average. The basic point is that E(log(X)) is not the same as Log(E(X)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. It turns out $p=e$ is exactly right, which all hinges on using the logarithm, and then transforming an infinite sum into an integral. My steps were pretty much the same:

Let $\tilde{N}$ denote the product after $j$ iterations. Then, we have $$\frac{\tilde{N}}{N_0} = \left(p \cdot r_1\right) \cdot \left(p \cdot r_2\right) \cdot \left(p \cdot r_3\right) \cdot \cdots \:,$$ where $p$ is constant, and each $r_j$ is a random number between $0$ and $1$. Next, take the natural log of both sides, turning the product on the right into sum:$$\ln\left(\frac{\tilde{N}}{N_0}\right) = \ln\left(p \cdot r_1\right) + \ln\left(p \cdot r_2\right) + \ln\left(p \cdot r_3\right) + \cdots$$

To satisfy the question as stated, we have the left side (on average) resolving to zero, with the number of terms on the right approaching infinity. This effectively makes $r$ a continuous variable: after many many iterations, we have sampled all of the real numbers between zero and one. Point is, we may replace the sum by an integral: $$0 \approx \ln\left(\frac{\tilde{N}}{N_0}\right) = \int_0^1 \left(\ln p + \ln r\right) dr \:,$$ and the answer falls right out. Only $p=e$ satisfies the above.